# How do I set up autoreply for some accounts on an anti-spam gateway?

Tags: spam, gateway, auto-reply

We have an [anti-spam gateway](http://www200.pair.com/mecham/spam/spamfilter20110303.html) set up which forwards mail to our exchange 2003 server.
This works fine, but now I need to add out of office replies. I'm trying to do so with gnarwl, but so far don't manage.

1. Is gnarwl a correct tool for this?
2. How should I set ldap up, should I replicate (a part of) the exchange database on the gateway to an ldap database of its own? Or, should I query the exchange database directly.
3. I need a few different types of messages, such as one for people no longer working here, another for maternity leave, another for vacations, etc. If Gnarwl uses only a single configuration file, how do I do this? Should I invoke it with different configuration files based on who the recipient is? If so, how do I do this?
4. Should I use something else instead? If so, which program? I don't want to create a load of users on our gateway just in order to use the vacation program.

The short version of the set up is:
A GNU/Linux system (Debian) with Postfix checks mails for spam and forwards to a Windows 2003 server running Exchange 2003.

Comment: Who don't you use the obvious solution of the native Exchange out-of-office notification?

Comment: Because I disable the accounts and remove the mailbox of people no longer working here, in order to cut down on licensing costs. This is after taking a backup of the mailbox. The address gets added to whomever replaces the person or to his/her former boss. So I can't just mark someone as out of office.